# ACRA integration and Google Drive

Tags: android, acra

Few days back I successfully integrated [ACRA](https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/BasicSetu) in project to get crash log, but due lots of entries I just deleted entire form but when I was trying to create new one, I am not able to get option to create new `legacy form within Tools`.

I followed same steps which I followed before but don't know what happen now, why I am not able to get option to create `Legacy form` within Tools inside spreadsheet.

your suggestion are appreciable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using Google Drive Forms as the ACRA reporting endpoint will not be supported anymore with the next releases.
```

I Suggest you to connect `BugSense` as your back-end for `ACRA` reports.
that what I set and it works great.

To get your crash report in `BugSense` you should:

**1.** Create an account.

**2.** place this line:

```
@ReportsCrashes(formUri = "http://www.bugsense.com/api/acra?api_key=key_received_from_bugsense", formKey="")
```

before declaration of your `Application` class:

http://blog.bugsense.com/post/8083993853/using-acra-and-bugsense

Comment: Seem bugsense is paid not free.

Comment: you have a free limited option.

Comment: you leave it blank, see added URL in the end of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's been axed. [Google did not take well](https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/Notice-on-Google-Form-Spreadsheet-usage) to this usage by ACRA anyway, so I suggest you look for an alternative. Once these forms become large enough they lose data too. Write your own custom POST action and link it up with ACRA or use a [third party provider](http://www.bugsense.com/docs/android#acra).